# Why do I got an error when stop gradle bootrun?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I'm getting an error when I stop a spring boot project starting with gradle by IntelliJ.
And the task manager still has a Java process no stop.
I need to stop it manually.

This is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'

}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8:19.3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
}
```

```
gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.4-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

the error with --debug --stacktrace

```
2023-10-11T00:06:47.494+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2023-10-11T00:06:47.494+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2023-10-11T00:06:47.494+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2023-10-11T00:06:47.494+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2023-10-11T00:06:47.494+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
2023-10-11T00:06:47.494+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Build cancelled while executing task ':bootRun'
2023-10-11T00:06:47.494+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.495+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:411)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:398)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:391)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:377)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.BuildCancelledException: Build cancelled while executing task ':bootRun'
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:49)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:77)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:58)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:54)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:32)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:57)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:38)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:63)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.496+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:30)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:176)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:76)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:47)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:43)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:32)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:39)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:25)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:102)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:95)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:83)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:96)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:52)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:83)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:54)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:88)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:88)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.497+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:46)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.498+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:34)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.498+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:43)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.498+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution$3.withWorkspace(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:286)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.498+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:43)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.498+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:33)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.498+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:40)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.498+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:30)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.498+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:54)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.498+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:40)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.498+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine.rebuild(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:46)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.498+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$0(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:182)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.498+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:182)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.499+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.499+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.499+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.499+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.511+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.512+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.513+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.514+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:411)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:398)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:391)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.516+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:377)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.517+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.517+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.517+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.517+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.517+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.517+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.517+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
2023-10-11T00:06:47.517+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2023-10-11T00:06:47.517+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2023-10-11T00:06:47.517+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
2023-10-11T00:06:47.517+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
2023-10-11T00:06:47.517+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 11s
```

How can I not get the error when I stop the bootrun?
I have tried the gradle version 7 but it also not work.

Comment: Can you try running the `bootRun` task with `--stacktrace`? Hopefully that will provide more insight as to the root cause of the exception.

Comment: Hi @wmkoch, I have changed the error log with  `--stacktrace --debug` for the question.